# Localize button in bottom appbar

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, winrt-xaml

How can I localize an button in the bottom appbar. I want to write on a german device 'Neu' under the button and on an english device 'Add'.

```
<Style x:Key="AddAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="AddAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Add"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE109;"/>
</Style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you are using the button styles you could do something like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource HomeAppBarButtonStyle}" x:Uid="HomeButton" />
```

And then in your RESW you'd have:

```
HomeButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

as your key value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to use the `Multilingual App Toolkit` for Visual Studio which allows you to change the content in your application depending on the user prefered language.

You can download it clicking this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh848309.aspx

and here is an short helpful video which shows how it works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyts-DQbC4w

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended method from Windows 8:

Example for a Button (C#)

1. Create a resource file: strings/de-de.resw
   In the Resource file you must type this:

`desplay.Text`      (first colum)
          `play the music here`(2th colum)
 2. Then add this parameter `x:Uid` to get translation from Resource file.

More information read this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965323(v=win.10).aspx